# JSF - custom tag - selectonemenu - ajax listener

Tags: ajax, jsf, listener, selectonemenu, actionevent

I use JSF2.2 and primefaces 5.2.

My page with native code of Primefaces. **IT WORKS**:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="continent" value="#{programController.continentCode}">

      <p:ajax listener="#{programController.onContinentChange}"
          update=searchForm:country" 
          immediate="true" />

      <f:selectItems value="#{programController.continent.listResult}" 
           var="item" 
           itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{item.code}" />

</p:selectOneMenu>
```

My page with my custom tag. **IT DOESN'T WORK**:

```
<mp:select_one id="continent" rendered="true" required="false"
                            label="#{bundleMessage['label.key']}"
                            value="#{programController.continentCode}"
                            list="#{programController.continents.listResult}"
                            item_label="#{item.name}" item_value="#{item.code}"
                            listener="programController.onContinentChange"
                            update="search_form:country" immediate="true"/>
```

My custom tag:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="#{id}" styleClass="#{styleClass}" required="#{required}" value="#{value}" rendered="#{rendered}">

       <p:ajax listener="#{listener}" 
               update="#{update}" 
               immediate="#{immediate}" />

        <f:selectItems value="#{list}" 
           var="item" 
           itemLabel="#{item_label}" itemValue="#{item_value}" />

</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Error reported with custom tag usage:

```
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase execute
WARNING: /WEB-INF/mp-tags/select_one.xhtml @119,33 listener="#{listener}": Identity 'listener' does not reference a MethodExpression instance, 
returned type: java.lang.String
javax.el.ELException: /WEB-INF/mp-tags/select_one.xhtml @119,33 listener="#{listener}": Identity 'listener' does not reference a MethodExpression instance, returned type: java.lang.String
```

My Controller:

```
public void onContinentChange() {
    LOGGER.logDebug(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> {%s}", continentCode);
    countries = list("COUNTRY_BY_CONTINENT", new String[] {continentCode});
}

public ListBean getCountries() {
    return countries;
}
```

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's because you're putting `String` value for `listener` attribute of the custom tag rather than a method expression. Wrap the attribute value by `#{` and `}` :

```
listener="#{programController.onContinentChange}"
```

Comment: if I use this expression I retrieve another error like "cannot exist property named 'onContinentChange' inside programController"

This is true because it is a method not a property with get/set methods.

Comment: What if you add brackets to the method : `"#{programController.onContinentChange()}"` ?

Comment: listener="programController.onContinentChange()" not work